# AWS Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/core/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, mod-wsgi

I have problem with AWS+Django+React. I do this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html . When i write "eb open"  i have some trouble "Error reading /opt/python/current/app/webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?". However when I run project locally in my virtual environment, everything works perfectly.

[Error 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0QZM.png)
[Error 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQhwv.png)

My code:

settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['django-decor-env.ffp8hmcfus.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com', '*']
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['core/templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "core/staticfiles" - update path.
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR

# Webpack config
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
'DEFAULT': {
    'CACHE': not DEBUG,
    'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '/',  # must end with slash
    'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
    'TIMEOUT': None,
  }
}
```

.exbetensions/python.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
  WSGIPath: decor/core/wsgi.py
```

.elasticbeanstalk/django-decor-env.env

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
NumProcesses: '1'
NumThreads: '15'
StaticFiles: /static/=static/
WSGIPath: core/wsgi.py
```

Project structure [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gZaA.png)

I've spent so much time solving this issue... Any helpful advices would be great for me.

**UPDATE:**
I decided my problem with S3, i watch my files on host and see that me file webpack-stats.json not push on AWS.  I upload webpack-stats.json and rebuild my project, sucesfully compiling, but now i have new problem [Internal Server Error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE6cP.png)
`eb logs` back:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=3438): Target WSGI script
'/opt/python/current/app/core/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Jun 12 22:43:17.606738 2018] [:error] [pid 3438] [remote 127.0.0.1:128]
mod_wsgi (pid=3438): Exception occurred processing WSGI script
'/opt/python/current/app/core/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jun 12 22:43:17.606898 2018] [:error] [pid 3438] [remote 127.0.0.1:128]
Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jun 12 22:43:17.606955 2018] [:error] [pid 3438] [remote 127.0.0.1:128]
File "/opt/python/current/app/core/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
[Tue Jun 12 22:43:17.606959 2018] [:error] [pid 3438] [remote 127.0.0.1:128]
application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Jun 12 22:43:17.606965 2018] [:error] [pid 3438] [remote 127.0.0.1:128]
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site
packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jun 12 22:43:17.606967 2018] [:error] [pid 3438] [remote 127.0.0.1:128]
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Jun 12 22:43:17.606972 2018] [:error] [pid 3438] [remote 127.0.0.1:128]
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site
packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Tue Jun 12 22:43:17.606974 2018] [:error] [pid 3438] [remote 127.0.0.1:128]
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
```

What i do wrong now? Thanks for attention..

Comment: You didn't include the details of the Python exception from the log file.

Comment: How can i do this? Im newbie on WSGI and Apache...

Comment: Immediately at the end of the stack trace for the exception, is a line which gives the exception type and the description of it. You just need to get it from the log file. You have missed out the follow line(s).

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same error, in my Django proyect in AWS using elasticbeanstalk, for anyone who is facing this issue I solved after many tries doing this:

1. run "eb config" and check the route for the WSGIPath , that should be:
   WSGIPath: yourApp/wsgi.py

2)downgrade Django to version 2.1.1 , I was using Django a different one and somehow there was an incompatibility.

Hope it helps

Comment: For me downgrading helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` ? Did you run `$ eb logs` 
Try to ssh into the machine and see where it created the file.

Most likely the wsgi error is that you are not importing the module correctly. It should be like

`import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<app_name>.settings")`

Comment: No, now target wsgi scripts cannot loaded as Python.. Internal error server 500..